# Cocos2D iPhone: have sprite fade to other sprite

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, sprite, transition, fade

In my game, I want a scene with a gray sprite. After two seconds, I want the sprite to fade into white (or fade into a form of the sprite that is white).

This acts kind of like the CSS3 transition property, where a thing can fade into another color. How is this possible in Cocos2D?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the CCFadeIn/CCFadeOut actions, you can apply that to the sprites to get the effect that you want.